# How to force Facebook to ask again about permission?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

To use my website, it is essential user need to give `pages_show_list` permission.

Seems after Facebook login, in development mode Facebook do not ask about granting permission, why?

The only way I worked it out is with Facebook Graph Explorer. It will force to show permission popup, and set permission.

But what about real time users? What if accidentally they do not grant permission, is it a way - not with Graph Explorer - from Facebook to give permission later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Play around witz the `auth_type` for that. You can also check for authorized permissions with the /me/permissions endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/permissions/